# gcc: How is integer division optimized?

Tags: gcc, optimization, integer-division

I've seen that gcc does a great job in optimizing integer divisions with a constant divisor.

E.g.

```
uint64_t f(uint64_t x)
{
    return x / 1000;
}

uint64_t f2(uint64_t x)
{
    return x / 10000;
}
```

becomes:

```
f:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        shr     rax, 3
        movabs  rdx, 2361183241434822607
        mul     rdx
        mov     rax, rdx
        shr     rax, 4
        pop     rbp
        ret
f2:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        movabs  rdx, 3777893186295716171
        mul     rdx
        mov     rax, rdx
        shr     rax, 11
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

It seems all divisions can be reduced to a shift + multiplication + shift (not always are all of those operations included).

How is this obtained and how can I get manually the required numbers for those three operations? I specifically need to know this for `uint64_t`,

Thanks a lot

Comment: Observe that 2^(64+3+4)=2361183241434822606848≈2361183241434822607*1000 and 2^(64+11)=37778931862957161709568≈3777893186295716171*10000.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi)

Comment: @NateEldredge This answer indeed covers most of what I need to know (e.g. libdivide is quite helpful)